# Спавн нпс как в gta 1-2

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d, tilemap

У кого-то есть предположения как реализован спавн нпс в первых двух частях гта (2d, top down) и как правильно это реализовать в unity?

Я собственно сделал спавн, он осуществлен так, В начале сцены все тайлы на которых могут появиться нпс, попадают в массив, потом этот массив начинает перебираться, что-ли, рандомным образом и если координаты тайла из перебора совпадают с нужными, к примеру на расстояние от 10 до 20 метров от гг, то на этих координатах спавнится нпс. Из минусов: нпс могут долго спавниться. И мне кажется, что это совсем не правильно.

Моих знаний хватило только на это. Хотел бы послушать ваши мысли, или даже советы, что нужно исправить в моём методе спавна. Я пробовал делать по разному(возможно где-то допускал ошибки), но только это сработало и критически на производительность не повлияло.

Comment: Если вам нужно создать NPC рядом с игроком, но на случайной точке, то нет смысла что то перебирать, просто сгенерируйте случайную точку рядом с NPS и займите соответсвующий ей тайл?

Comment: По-моему, похоже на ошибку [XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): вы хотите сделать спавн, как в гта, однако что вы просите - так это исправить ошибки *вашего* метода, который по-вашему подходит. Проблема в том, что вы, возоможно, думаете, что 100% людей играли в гта и понимают, что вам надо, однако это не так. Допустим, я ни разу не играл – я не имею ни малейшего понятия, что вы хотите. Поэтому вам следует добавить в вопрос четкое описание того, что вам требуется, а не "как в гта"

Answer (score 0):

Вы так уверены, что в gta есть какие-то там тайлы в логике npc... pathfinding может быть, но скорее всего на этом всё (что касается npc).

Скорее всего в gta 1, 2 проставлены споты для спавна тех или иных мобов. На тратуарах проставлены уже заготовленные графы, где каждая точка это спот для обычных пешиходы. На дорогах тоже самое для машин. У бандитов просто споты с патрулём в проставленных местах.